# How to get number without null before dot?

Tags: sql, postgresql, char

I need
.00012 $
from 0.00012
but
1.0002 $ from 1.0002
Is this possible in postgress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like below -

```
With t as
(Select 1.0002 As Value
UNION ALL
Select .00012 As Value
)
Select to_char(Value,concat('FM$999,999,999,990D',repeat('0',length(cast(Value as varchar))-2))) from t;
```

Below is a DB fiddle link to illustrate - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=a8e9a3207305b011f5bf7be58ce04180

**EDIT : As I thought more about the problem, I realized that the solution above would work for the examples that you have shared but it is not a generalized solution. Below would be a more general approach to solve the problem :**

```
With t as
(Select 1.0002 As Value
UNION ALL
Select .00012 As Value
UNION ALL
Select 100.003 As Value
UNION ALL
Select 12.34456 As Value
UNION ALL
Select 5000.30 As Value
)
Select to_char(Value,concat('FM$999,999,999,990D',repeat('0',length(cast(Value as varchar))-length(cast(ROUND(Value,0) as varchar))-1))) As Amt from t;
```

DB fiddle link - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=ff6f59fdd499941ee1cb1e0fc57e08ca